# How to get camera permission in system service?

Tags: android

I am using camera in my remote service. I am getting camera permission in remote service.
But now i am using system service .In system service i want to access camera.But I cannot 
access the camera.So how can i get the permission in system service in android.

Comment: Err, what? I've read this question three times I have no idea what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Add the CAMERA permissions in Manifest file.

Comment: As i know there is no manifest file in system service in the framework.Then how to access the camera in the framework using system service.